# putextra puts content in ram memory in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'd like to know where putextra puts content when I do something like the code below. Value stays in RAM memory?

`intent.putExtra("name","value");`

If I use the code below in destiny activity, then the value is removed from memory?

`getIntent().removeExtra("name")`

Comment: The value is stored in the memory of the app when executing. And when removed, it is as  is, removed from the scope of the application, perhaps garbage collected. So what's the question?